# mongoDB and React filters

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-hooks, react-router

I get an 'undefined' string in my post method. In my Home file on line 95 I use a filter for my busMobel where the status field has default: 'Yet to Start' and it works, only 'Yet to Start' buses are shown, but the filters (which are written just above) do nothing.

Home:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { axiosInstance } from '../helpers/axiosInstance';
import { HideLoading, ShowLoading } from '../redux/alertsSlice';
import { Col, Row, message } from 'antd';
import Bus from '../components/Bus';
import axios from 'axios';

function Home() {
  const { user } = useSelector(state => state.users);
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [buses, setBuses] = useState([]);

  const getBuses = useCallback(async () => {
    const tempFilters = {};
    Object.keys(filters).forEach((key) => {
      if (filters[key]) {
        tempFilters[key] = filters[key];
      }
    });
    try {
      dispatch(ShowLoading());
      const response = await axios.post(
        "/api/buses/get-all-buses",
        tempFilters,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          },
        }
      );
      dispatch(HideLoading());
      if (response.data.success) {
        setBuses(response.data.data);
      } else {
        message.error(response.data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(HideLoading());
      message.error(error.message);
    }
  }, [dispatch, filters]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getBuses();
    // setSelectedBus();
  }, [getBuses]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='my-3 py-1'>
        <Row gutter={10}>
          <Col lg={6} sm={24}>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='From'
              value={filters.from}
              onChange={(e) => setFilters({ ...filters, from: e.target.value })} // maybe this part is wrong :(
            />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={6} sm={24}>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='To'
              value={filters.to}
              onChange={(e) => setFilters({ ...filters, to: e.target.value })}// maybe this part is wrong :(
            />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={6} sm={24}>
            <input
              type='date'
              placeholder='Date'
              value={filters.journeyDate}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setFilters({ ...filters, journeyDate: e.target.value }) // maybe this part is wrong :(
              }
            />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={6} sm={24} >
            <div className='d-flex gap-2'>
              <button className='primary-btn' onClick={getBuses}>
                Filter
              </button>
              <button className='outlined' onClick={() => setFilters({})}>
                Clear
              </button>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Row gutter={[15, 15]}>
          {buses
            .filter((bus) => bus.status === 'Yet to start') // maybe this part is wrong :(
            .map((bus) => (
              <Col lg={12} xs={24} sm={24} key={bus.id}>
                <Bus bus={bus} />
              </Col>
            ))}
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

busesRoute post metod get-all-buses

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Bus = require("../models/busModel")
const authMiddleware = require("../middlewares/authMiddleware")


// add-bus

router.post('/add-bus', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const existingBus = await Bus.findOne({ number: req.body.number })

        if (existingBus) {
            return res.status(200).send({
                seccess: false,
                meggage: 'Bus already exists',
            })
        }
        const newBus = new Bus(req.body);
        await newBus.save();
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Bus added successfully'
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            meggage: error.message
        })
    }
});

// update-bus

router.post("/update-bus", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Bus.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body)
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Bus updated successfully',
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({success: false, message: error.meggage})
    }
});

// delete-bus

router.post("/delete-bus", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Bus.findByIdAndDelete(req.body._id, req.body)
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Bus deleted    successfully',
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({success: false, message: error.meggage})
    }
});


// get-all-buses

router.post("/get-all-buses", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body.filters) // res -> undefined
        const buses = await Bus.find(req.body.filters);
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Buses fetched successfully",
            data: buses,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        })
    };
})


//get-bus-by-id

router.post("/get-bus-by-id", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const bus = await Bus.findById(req.body._id);
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Buses fetched successfully",
            data: bus,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        })
    };
})




module.exports = router;
```

busModel:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const busSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    number : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    capacity : {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    from : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    to : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    journeyDate : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    departure : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    arrival : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    type : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    fare : {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    seatsBooked : {
        type: Array,
        default:[]
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Yet to Start',
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('buses', busSchema)
```

In get-bus-by-id i use `const bus = await Bus.findById(req.body._id);`  becouse is i write `const bus = await Bus.findById(req.body);`   i got no buses

Comment: In `axios.post` instead of `tempFilters` try `{ filters: tempFilters }`